# insert into database having large number of parameter

Tags: java, sql

i have to insert data into database .Because sql statement VALUES(......) have 8 parameters . Is it proficient way to use insert statement ?

```
    Class UserRegistration {
public void insertToDatabase(){
       String sql=" INSERT INTO db1(......) Values(id,fname,lastname,username,password,usertype,email,contact,address )"
}


}
```

Comment: Yes.  `INSERT` is the typical way for inserting rows into a database.

Comment: It's better if you normalize your database, at least until the third normal form. But you can insert 8 or more parameters.

Comment: Did you find any drawback in your current implementation using `INSERT` ? I don't think so

Comment: In real life 8 parameters are not considered a large number. I have done it with 25, and I would expect it to work with 1000 or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do it in Java, assuming you're using JDBC, is to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO db1" +
            " (id,fname,lastname,username,password,usertype,email,contact,address)" +
            " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt   (1, id);
    stmt.setString(2, fname);
    stmt.setString(3, lastname);
    stmt.setString(4, username);
    stmt.setString(5, password);
    stmt.setString(6, usertype);
    stmt.setString(7, email);
    stmt.setString(8, contact);
    stmt.setString(9, address);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```